# Разметка sh/bash скриптов

Tags: bash, разметка

По работе иногда приходится читать старые скрипты, часто разметка в них отсутствует, что увеличивает время поиска нужного блока или проблемы. Так как это все находится на сервере без GUI, то разметку с помощью редакторов выполнить проблематично.

Для примера простое сравнение:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ${1} == ${2} ]]; then
echo "Параметры идентичны"
else
echo "параметры различаются"
fi
```

Удобнее будет читать, если будут установлены отступы:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ${1} == ${2} ]]; then
    echo "Параметры идентичны"
else
    echo "параметры различаются"
fi
```

Comment: А что, `vim` на сервере тоже нет?

Comment: @Ainar-G `vim` не пользуюсь, а так думается что он из коробки идет. Если вы знаете как с помощью vim сделать разметку, то добавьте ответом пожалуйста, мне бы это пригодилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `vim`:

```sh
$ vim +"normal! gg=G" +"wq" ./file.bash
```

Выполняет в нормальном режиме команду «перейти в начало файла
и отформатировать до конца файла» и выходит.

Comment: файл форматируется достаточно хорошо, но возникла проблема с циклом `... | while read ...;do ` завершение цикла в начале файла стало, т.е. получилось `^done` на следующей строке `^fi`, но неоспоримый плюс этого решения - оно проще, спасибо!

Comment: @PotroNik  Все параметры форматирования в `vim` довольно хорошо поддаются кастомизации.  Если будет время и желание, можете посмотреть, например, тут: https://vimhelp.org/usr_30.txt.html.  И вообще на этом сайте.